# Is the ball $\{f\in W^{m, 2}(0,1): \|f-\psi\|_{\infty} \leq 1 \}$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces

As the title suggests, I would like to know whether the set

> $$\{ f\in W^{m, 2}(0,1): \|f-\psi\|_{\infty} \leq 1 \}$$

is sequentially compact in $W^{m,2}(0,1)$. Here, $W^{m,2}(0,1)$ denotes the Sobolev space of functions defined on $(0,1)$ that have square integrable $m$th derivatives and norm

$$\|f\|_{W^{m,2}} = \sqrt{\|f\|^2_{L^2} + \|f^{(m)}\|_{L^2}^2}$$

and $\|f\|_{\infty}$ stands for the $\sup_{x \in (0,1)} |f(x)|$, the uniform norm. I believe that the set is indeed sequentially compact and this can be shown by an application of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Is this correct?

Comment: @daw $W^{m,2}$. I''ll state it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this set is not compact in $W^{m,2}$. It is not even bounded. Take $\psi=0$,
$$
v_n(x):=\sin(n\pi x).
$$
Then the $v_n$ are in the set, but $\|v_n \|_{H^m}\to\infty$ for all $m\ge1$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you very much. The Arzela-Ascoli theorem can then be applied to show compactness in $L^{\infty}$?

Comment: @JohnK This set is not compact in $L^\infty$. The sequence $v_n$ from above does not possess a convergent subsequence in $L^\infty$. To use compactness of embedding you need boundedness in $W^{m,2}$ which doesn't hold (as shown above).

Comment: Arzela-Ascoli gives compactness in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: The sequence $( n^{-1/2}v_n))$ converges to zero in $L^\infty$, but is still unbounded in $W^m$ for $m\ge1$.

Comment: @daw I don't understand what you are trying to prove by last comment. Anyway if sequence $v_n$ possesses a convergent subsequence in $L_\infty$ then this subsequence is also convergent in $L^2$. This is not possible since sequence $v_n$ is orthonormal there. How will you prove the compactness in $L^\infty$ if don't have boundedness in $W^{m,2}$ (compact embedding work only for bounded subsets; image of unbounded subset can be not compact)